# try and catch issue in c# windows application

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, ado.net

When I execute my program, the execution must step into catch when there's an existing item

```
con2=new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0DataSource=e:\\convert.accdb" + "; Persist Security Info=False");
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, con2);           
con2.Open();           
try {
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  con2.Close();
  MessageBox.Show("Thanks");
}
catch (Exception ex) {
  MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
  con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Not clear about "the execution must step into catch when there's an existing item" ?

Answer (score 2):

The `catch` part will only be evaluated if there is an error within the `try` block. So, if the call causes an exception then it will fall into that block, or if you raise one, it will, too.

`ExecuteNonQuery` returns an `int`, so, if you want to throw an exception when, say, it returns more than 0, then do:

```
con2.Open();

try {
  if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0) {
    throw new Exception("More than zero rows affected");
  }
  con2.Close();
  MessageBox.Show("Thnaks");
}
catch (Exception ex) {
 MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
 con.Close();
}
```

But even this leaves a lot to be desired. For instance, you could use `finally` for management of connections (and your command, as they are disposable also):

```
try {
  if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0) {
    throw new Exception("More than zero rows affected");
  }
  MessageBox.Show("Thanks");
}
catch (Exception ex) {
 MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
finally {
  con.Close();
  con2.Close();
  cmd.Close();
}
```

And further yet, are you sure you want to use exceptions to handle flow of execution? This is generally frowned upon, as exceptions, as per their name, are considered in exceptional circumstances. Instances in which you know what could happen is hardly exceptional.

Comment: I'm working on a database converter which converts basically from MS sql-server to MS Access Data Base,when the user select the intended table to be converted, he may mistake by converting the table again which makes a duplication of tables.I want a message box exception to show that there's an existing table 'table name'.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for something like this. You need to catch SqlException then iterate through its Errors collection to find a message that matches the error you're expecting.

```
try
{
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  con2.Close();
  MessageBox.Show("Thanks");
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < ex.Errors.Count; i++)
   {
        if (ex.Errors[i].Message.Contains("There is already an object named"))
        {
             /* Handle duplicate situation here */
             break;
        }
   }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
  con.Close();
}
```